# Focusing a Tab after it has been reloaded via window.open?

Tags: javascript, tabs, focus, window.open, tabbed

In my webapp I work with new Tabs I open with window.open. Sometimes, a tab with the target-name is already open in the background and the window.open(..., "sametarget") only reloads it, which is fine - but the Tab stays in the background after reloading, which is not. Is there any way (JavaScript? window.open parameter?) to get it to the foreground after reloading? Or is this prohibited by browser security?
I am trying this in IE7 / IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Does `window.focus()` solve your problem?

---

**EDIT**

Possibly not: [Possible to set tab focus in IE7 from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943/possible-to-set-tab-focus-in-ie7-from-javascript)

Comment: I tried window.focus(), didn't seem to do anything. I would be happy already, if there were a browser setting to focus automatically on reloaded tabs or something along those lines, but I don't think there is...