# Jquery to focus on main tab on time out in IE8

Tags: jquery, html

I have a web application where in I check if the user is inactive for 28 mins and display a pop-up on the main page asking user if he wants to extend the session 'Yes' or 'No' for the next 2 mins. Once he clicks on 'Yes' I extend the session 30 more minutes else i kill the session if no action is taken. The whole logic of this time out is in Jquery.

My problem is when a user clicks on any hyperlink in my page and opens it in the new tab and remains inactive for 28 mins on the newly opened tab the user is not getting the alert on the new tab but he has the alert popped up on the main tab. The user is unaware that the session is inactive for 28 mins. Can you please suggest me a way where in i can switch the tab so that the user can see the alert on the main tab?

Thanks in Advance,
Rutwik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the research i have done i found that there is no way to control inactive tab from active tab of the same browser window.

i found out a nice work around for this problem  @ http://heyman.info/2010/sep/30/jquery-title-alert/

This will flash an alert on the title bar of the tab. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Possible to set tab focus in IE7 from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943/possible-to-set-tab-focus-in-ie7-from-javascript)

This should answer you. Though it is about the new Popup windows. The Logic is still the same:

"You are not allowed to enter too much in the user space!"