# How to change tab using javascript in a tab container in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I am using the Ajax toolkit tab container.

I have a javascript function which changes the active tab, which is working perfectly in firefox.However in IE, it does work, but the tab doesnt change untill all the javascript is executed e.g.

```
//do something 
ChangeTab()
//do something else
//do something else
```

I re written the changetab function in all the ways i have found online, they all work in IE just not when I need it to.

Any suggestions much appreciated

I have tried the following

```
$find('<%=TabContainer1.ClientID%>').set_activeTabIndex(2);
```

and

```
var ctrl = $find(tabControl);
ctrl.set_activeTab(ctrl.get_tabs()[tabNumber]);
```

Answer (score 0):

please see response here:

[Possible to set tab focus in IE7 from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943/possible-to-set-tab-focus-in-ie7-from-javascript)

So, it means that this is not possible in Internet Explorer.